# Масштабирование картинки с сохранением пропорций

Tags: html, css, javascript

У меня есть такой `div`:

```css
.photoBorder {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.photoImage {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 20px;" align="center" class="photoBorder">
  <img align="center" src="<c:url value=" /profile/showPhoto?${currentTime} "/>" class="photoImage" alt="" id="myimage" />
</div>
```

Все хорошо работает, если картинка больше, чем размеры `div`. А если картинка маленькая, то она так маленькая и рисуется. Как сделать, чтобы она увеличивалась до размеров `div`, но сохраняла пропорции? Причём я не знаю, что у неё больше: высота или ширина. И ещё надо, чтобы она располагалась по центру, а свободные края заполнялись чёрным цветом.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо max-height задать height: auto;

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Так же маленькая картинка остается маленькой.

Comment: То есть вы хотите одновременно и сохранять пропорции, и растягивать картинку во всю высоту и ширину дива?

Comment: Я хочу сохранять пропорции, а катринку растягивать на div так, чтобы либо по ширине, либо по длине уперлась в края.

Comment: Для заполнения свободных краев можно использовать background.

Для сохранения пропорций достаточно указывать только одно измерение width или height

А вот какое именно измерение указать, тот тут на ум мне приходит только использовать JavaScript. Ну для примера:

    $( window ).ready(function(){
        var img = $("#myimage"); 
        img.attr("naturalWidth") > img.attr("naturalHeight") ? img.attr("width","120px") : img.attr("height","120px");
    })

Как это сделать через CSS не придумал.

Comment: А откуда эту функцию вызывать?

Comment: В данном случае она написана с использованием библиотеки JQuery, поэтому если есть возможность, желательно ее подсоединить в header и написать эту функцию ниже в любом месте(вызовется сама как картинки подгрузятся на страницу).

Comment: Неправильно что-то работает. Она вытянивает картинку на всю область и по длине и по высоте. Может надо ненужный атрибут отменять как-то?

Comment: Что-то перемудрил я, наверное, jquery отказался читать attr("naturalHeight"), вот так теперь должно нормально работать [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g80bobx4/1/):

    $( document ).ready(function(){
        var img = $("#myimage");
        img[0].naturalWidth >= img[0].naturalHeight ? img.attr("width","120px") : img.attr("height","120px");
    })

Answer (score 2):

Если не интересует поддержка старых версий IE, и картинка может быть бэкграундом, то к div

```
<div style="background-image: url(/profile/showPhoto?${currentTime}); background-color: #000" class="photoBorder"></div>
```

нужно применить следующие стили:

```
.photoBorder {
margin-top: 20px;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;

//стили которые непостредственно масштабируют картинку с сохранением пропорций
background-repeat     : no-repeat;
background-size       : cover;
background-position-x : 50%;
background-position-y : 50%;
}
```

Comment: Alex: теперь все время true дает и поэтому ширину выставляет.
____
Похоже, у него нет naturalHeight вообще.
____
А нет, нашла, все есть, но что-то все равно не работает.

Comment: А зачем Вам JavaScript? Я предложил Вам решение на чистом CSS, как Вы и хотели.

Comment: У меня картинка меняется скриптом, а я не уверена, что ее так же легко можно поменять, если она в background задана. Во всяком случае это тоже надо пробовать. Поэтому я сначала пробую один вариант. Если не получится, то попробую Ваш тоже. И потом, тогда я ведь не смогу задать background чернам цветом, или можно тоже?
____

то Alex, в другом совсем дело. Эта функция вызывается только при прорисовке окна, а потом я меняю картинку, а она уже не вызывается.

Comment: Я подправил ответ непосредственно под Ваш код. Возможно, это внесет некоторую ясность. К вопросу того, что не работает Javascript: нужно делать пересчет всех размеров на image.onload.

Comment: Не получается со вторым вариантом тоже. Дает ошибку 404 на адрес, где картинка берется, хотя адрес правильный показывает. А как навесить на image.onload?
____
Уже нашла сама. Спасибо большое, zhenyab и Alex Krass. Вы мне очень помогли.